# how to convert unstructured text file to structured one?

Tags: java, file

I just need to know how or a way to start it, If i be using JAVA for this what modules or api's should i know in JAVA ?

i have a text file like this

```
REC_CODE ORDER_ID    CUSTOMER_ID   ORDER_DATE
ORD  1     1 01-01-2001
LIN 1   1    1 1
LIN    1 2 2   3
LIN   1 3  1   2
ORD 2 3    02-01-2001
LIN      2 1 1 1
LIN 2    2 2 3
LIN 2   3 1   2
```

If you see this data carefully ORD corresponds to the Order Level details where as LIN corresponds to Line details of the Order, The problem is the file is not delimited or having fixed width this varies as you can see there are single space and multiple spaces in file.

I want to convert this to delimited type, Can you suggest some methods to do so, I am okay to use any tool or language but preferably JAVA, Please let me know how can this be done in JAVA, so i would know where exactly should i start and the limitations. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: this can be done with java but provided there is a particular way the data will come as of now like if spaces is the only issue it can be resolved but can it contains other wild chars?

Comment: Thanks for response Rahul, nope it wont contain any wild chars.

Comment: Actually, it is delimited.  The fields are *whitespace* delimited.  And as such it is easy to parse using `Scanner` or even `String.split("\\s+")`

Comment: Thanks for tip Stephen, will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Java Pattern. Write right pattern with more than one space delimiters and parse your line.
Here more about [patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). 
And some [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Comment: Thanks Kutsyk, I will check it out.